# Is there a better and faster way to compute some statistics stored in a variable and assign the results to new columns also stored in a variable?

Tags: r, data.table

I wonder if there would be a faster way to compute some statistics stored in a variable and assign the results to new columns also stored in a variable? I've created a function called "count" because I want to count only valid numbers (non-missing).

In this example, the variable *stc* will vary and it can contain a single statistic and multiple, i.e.:

```
stc = c("mean)
stc = c("mean", "sd")
stc = c("max", "min", "count)"
```

```
library("data.table")
library("glue")
tbl <- data.table(ID = paste0("ID", 1:9),
                  TR = rnorm(9),
                  GR = c("A", "A", "B", "C", "A", "C", "A", "B", "B"))


trt <- "New.Name"
rhs <- "TR"
blk <- "GR"
stc <- c("Mean", "Count")

count <- function(x, na.rm = TRUE) {
  sum(!is.na(x), na.rm = na.rm)
}

lhr_expr <- glue(paste0("c('", paste(trt, stc, sep = '.', collapse = "', '"), "')"))
rhs_expr <- glue("list({glue_collapse(glue('{tolower(stc)}({rhs}, na.rm = TRUE)'), sep = ', ')})")
tbl[, eval(rlang::parse_expr(glue("({lhr_expr}) := {rhs_expr}"))), by = blk]
```

The results would be:

```
    ID         TR GR New.Name.Mean New.Name.Count
1: ID1  2.9521189  A     0.6473405              4
2: ID2 -0.5643511  A     0.6473405              4
3: ID3  0.5951386  B     0.2703137              3
4: ID4  0.4977452  C     0.2890320              2
5: ID5 -0.9350095  A     0.6473405              4
6: ID6  0.0803188  C     0.2890320              2
7: ID7  1.1366038  A     0.6473405              4
8: ID8 -0.2496585  B     0.2703137              3
9: ID9  0.4654609  B     0.2703137              3
```

**Update:**

I've updated the code and added all suggestions up to now to perform a benchmark.

`fun1` was suggested by *Roland*

`fun3` and `fun4` was suggested by *Cole*

`fun5` was suggested by *MrSmithGoesToWashington*

```
library("data.table")
library("benchr")
library("glue")
n <- 1000000
p_miss <- 0.05
dat <- data.table(ID = paste0("ID", 1:n),
                  TR = sample(c(rnorm((1 - p_miss)*n), rep(NA_real_, p_miss*n))),
                  GR = sample(paste0("GR", 1:500), n, replace = TRUE))

fun0 <- function(tbl, trt, rhs, blk, stc) {
  tbl <- copy(tbl)
  count <- function(x, na.rm = TRUE) {
    sum(!is.na(x), na.rm = na.rm)
  }
  lhr_expr <- glue(paste0("c('", paste(trt, stc, sep = '.', collapse = "', '"), "')"))
  rhs_expr <- glue(".({glue_collapse(glue('{tolower(stc)}({rhs}, na.rm = TRUE)'), sep = ', ')})")
  tbl[, eval(rlang::parse_expr(glue("({lhr_expr}) := {rhs_expr}"))), by = blk]
}

fun1 <- function(tbl, trt, rhs, blk, stc) {
  tbl <- copy(tbl)
  count <- function(x, na.rm = TRUE) {
    sum(!is.na(x), na.rm = na.rm)
  }
  for (fun in stc) {
    FUN <- as.name(tolower(fun))
    RHS <- as.name(rhs)
    eval(bquote(
      tbl[, paste(trt, fun, sep = ".") := .(FUN)(.(RHS), na.rm = TRUE), by = blk, verbose = FALSE][]
    ))
  }
  return(tbl)
}

fun2 <- function(tbl, trt, rhs, blk, stc) {
  tbl <- copy(tbl)
  count <- function(x, na.rm = TRUE) {
    sum(!is.na(x), na.rm = na.rm)
  }
  dt_expr <- paste0(glue("{trt}.{stc}"), " = ", glue('{tolower(stc)}({rhs}, na.rm = TRUE)'), collapse = ', ')
  tbl_blk <- tbl[, eval(rlang::parse_expr(glue(".({dt_expr})"))), by = blk]
  tbl <- merge(tbl, tbl_blk, by = blk, all.x = TRUE)
  return(tbl)
}

fun3 <- function(tbl, trt, rhs, blk, stc) {
  count <- function(x, na.rm = TRUE) {
    sum(!is.na(x), na.rm = na.rm)
  }
  tbl <- copy(tbl)
  NSE_expr <- substitute(tbl[, (paste(trt, stc, sep = ".")) := my_call, blk],
                        list(my_call = as.call(c(quote(list), lapply(stc, function(x) as.call(list(str2lang(tolower(x)), str2lang(rhs), na.rm = TRUE)))))))
  tbl <- eval(NSE_expr)[]
  return(tbl)
}

fun4 <- function(tbl, trt, rhs, blk, stc) {
  tbl <- copy(tbl)
  count <- function(x, na.rm = TRUE) {
    sum(!is.na(x), na.rm = na.rm)
  }
  tbl <- tbl[, (paste(trt, stc, sep = ".")) := lapply(stc, function(x) eval(call(tolower(x), str2lang(rhs), na.rm = TRUE))), blk]
  return(tbl)
}

fun5 <- function(tbl, trt, rhs, blk, stc) {
  tbl <- copy(tbl)
  count <- function(x, na.rm = TRUE) sum(!is.na(x))
  lhr_expr <- glue(paste0("c('", paste(trt, stc, sep = '.', collapse = "', '"), "')"))
  rhs_expr <- glue(".({glue_collapse(glue('{tolower(stc)}({rhs}, na.rm = TRUE)'), sep = ', ')})")
  tbl <- eval(rlang::parse_expr(paste0("tbl[, ",lhr_expr," := ",rhs_expr, ", by = ", blk, "]")))
  return(tbl)
}
```

**Benchmark**

It is great to see different approaches to optimize such code, even when it is just a few milliseconds.

```
res <- benchr::benchmark(
  tbl0 = fun0(tbl = dat, trt = "New.Name", rhs = "TR", blk = "GR", stc = c("Mean", "Count", "Min", "Max", "Var", "SD")),
  tbl1 = fun1(tbl = dat, trt = "New.Name", rhs = "TR", blk = "GR", stc = c("Mean", "Count", "Min", "Max", "Var", "SD")),
  tbl2 = fun2(tbl = dat, trt = "New.Name", rhs = "TR", blk = "GR", stc = c("Mean", "Count", "Min", "Max", "Var", "SD")),
  tbl3 = fun3(tbl = dat, trt = "New.Name", rhs = "TR", blk = "GR", stc = c("Mean", "Count", "Min", "Max", "Var", "SD")),
  tbl4 = fun4(tbl = dat, trt = "New.Name", rhs = "TR", blk = "GR", stc = c("Mean", "Count", "Min", "Max", "Var", "SD")),
  tbl5 = fun5(tbl = dat, trt = "New.Name", rhs = "TR", blk = "GR", stc = c("Mean", "Count", "Min", "Max", "Var", "SD"))
)

print(res, order = "median")

Benchmark summary:
Time units : milliseconds 
 expr n.eval min lw.qu median mean up.qu max total relative
 tbl0    100 168   199    221  235   250 747 23500     1.00
 tbl3    100 168   195    230  238   269 557 23800     1.04
 tbl5    100 174   206    232  239   264 515 23900     1.05
 tbl2    100 170   216    245  267   281 768 26700     1.11
 tbl1    100 182   240    268  291   319 601 29100     1.22
 tbl4    100 423   480    524  571   624 969 57100     2.37
```

[image]

Whithout using `copy(tbl)` the `median` was the same for `fun0`, `fun3` and `fun5`.

```
Benchmark summary:
Time units : milliseconds 
 expr n.eval min lw.qu median mean up.qu max total relative
 tbl3    100 147   152    158  167   168 276 16700     1.00
 tbl0    100 148   153    158  169   165 478 16900     1.00
 tbl5    100 149   152    158  165   166 242 16500     1.00
 tbl1    100 169   180    185  200   196 504 20000     1.17
 tbl2    100 199   238    261  276   287 640 27600     1.65
 tbl4    100 424   442    463  488   500 758 48800     2.93
```

It seems that `fun5` results are more stable between replicates.

Thank you.

Comment: No, that's not how we benchmark data.table code. The package is optimized for large data.tables. You should have at least a few hundred thousand observations and a few thousand groups. For small input, data.table optimizations hurt performance due to overhead. Why are you trying to optimize timings that are in milliseconds?

Comment: I just increased the size to ```1000000``` observations and the groups to ```500```, would that be enough to benchmark data.table code.

Comment: Are you sure the ```copy(tbl)``` is necessary ?

Comment: Actually, it is not necessary, I just used it because the functions perform an in-place modification to ```tbl```. If I don't do that the ```tbl``` is modified. So I added to all of them.

Comment: then, why about changing the name of the parameter in the function, and removing the copy ? Say ```function(tblx, ``` ..

Comment: Even using a different name it points to the original table so it changes it as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using base NSE, we can create a call using `substitute()` which will allow the package to inspect the language to do internal optimization. This is a similar concept to @Roland's `bquote()` method.

```r
f3 = function (dt, trt, rhs, blk, stc, verbose = FALSE, na.rm = FALSE) {
  count <- function(x, na.rm = TRUE) {
    sum(!is.na(x), na.rm = na.rm)
  }
  dt = copy(dt)
  
  NSE_expr = substitute(dt[, (paste(trt, stc, sep = ".")) := my_call, blk],
                        list(my_call = as.call(c(quote(list),
                                                 lapply(stc, 
                                                        function(x) as.call(list(str2lang(tolower(x)), str2lang(rhs),na.rm = na.rm)))))))
  if (verbose) print(NSE_expr)
  eval(NSE_expr)[]

## another way that is simpler but would not be optimized.
  # dt[, (paste(trt, stc, sep = ".")) := lapply(stc, function(x) eval(call(tolower(x), str2lang(rhs)))), blk]
}

f3(tbl, trt = "New.Name", rhs = "TR", blk = "GR", stc = c("Count", "Min", "Max", "Var", "SD"), verbose = TRUE, na.rm = TRUE)

## dt[, `:=`((paste(trt, stc, sep = ".")), list(count(TR, 
##     na.rm = TRUE), min(TR, na.rm = TRUE), max(TR, na.rm = TRUE), 
##     var(TR, na.rm = TRUE), sd(TR, na.rm = TRUE))), blk]


##                 ID         TR    GR New.Name.Count New.Name.Min New.Name.Max New.Name.Var New.Name.SD
##       1:       ID1 -0.3563480 GR258           1948    -3.331128     3.348017    0.9632764   0.9814665
##       2:       ID2  0.1282964 GR110           1850    -3.183015     4.221554    0.9867797   0.9933679
##       3:       ID3  1.4644653 GR315           1921    -3.883513     3.370857    0.9816817   0.9907985
##       4:       ID4  2.0069751 GR389           1868    -2.963830     3.025912    0.9694042   0.9845832
##       5:       ID5 -0.1360678 GR297           1861    -3.404720     3.312634    0.9924292   0.9962074
##      ---                                                                                             
##  999996:  ID999996 -0.6020616 GR486           1810    -3.586257     2.860834    0.9639179   0.9817932
##  999997:  ID999997 -0.1017354 GR436           1877    -3.850322     3.159463    0.9789052   0.9893964
##  999998:  ID999998  0.1922223 GR154           1860    -3.244041     3.258786    0.9634926   0.9815766
##  999999:  ID999999         NA GR393           1952    -3.311030     3.847588    1.0350633   1.0173806
## 1000000: ID1000000 -0.2522882 GR306           1881    -3.422210     3.582373    1.0634541   1.0312391
```

Answer (score 2):

This uses at least some data.table optimization for the mean calculation on my system:

```
for (fun in stc) {
  FUN <- as.name(tolower(fun))
  RHS <- as.name(rhs)
  eval(bquote(
    tbl[, paste(trt, fun, sep = ".") := 
          .(FUN)(.(RHS)), 
        by = blk, verbose = TRUE][]
  ))
}
```

Can't test performance because you didn't provide a suitable and representative example. So, please benchmark yourself.

(Note that you need to adjust if you use `.()` as a shortcut for `list` within data.table. You could use `substitute` instead of `bquote` then, or even that glue stuff.)

Comment: Thank you @Roland for your response. I've updated my question with a reproducible example and a benchmark.

Answer (score 0):

May be you could use .N from data.table instead of you count function ..
For exemple, try this :

```
fun0bis <- function(dt, trt, rhs, blk, stc) {
  tbl <- data.table(tbl)
  stc <- tolower(stc)
  if (length(grepl(stc, pattern = "count")) >0)
  {
    text <- paste0(deparse(substitute(dt)), "[,", trt,".", "Count := .N, by = '",blk,"']")
    eval(parse(text = text))
    stc <- stc[which(!grepl(stc, pattern = "count"))]
  }
  lhr_expr <- glue(paste0("c('", paste(trt, stc, sep = '.', collapse = "', '"), "')"))
  rhs_expr <- glue(".({glue_collapse(glue('{tolower(stc)}({rhs}, na.rm = TRUE)'), sep = ', ')})")
  tbl <- tbl[, eval(rlang::parse_expr(glue("({lhr_expr}) := {rhs_expr}"))), by = blk]
  return(tbl)
}
```

**EDIT**
After the comment, and some test, I think there could be a light improvment with :

```
fun0bis <- function(dt, trt, rhs, blk, stc) {
  count <- function(x, na.rm = TRUE) sum(!is.na(x))
  lhr_expr <- glue(paste0("c('", paste(trt, stc, sep = '.', collapse = "', '"), "')"))
  rhs_expr <- glue(".({glue_collapse(glue('{tolower(stc)}({rhs}, na.rm = TRUE)'), sep = ', ')})")
  return(eval(rlang::parse_expr(paste0("tbl[, ",lhr_expr," := ",rhs_expr, ", by = ", blk, "]"))))
}
```

Comment: This was my first attempt, but the special symbol ```.N```counts the number of rows, so if there is any missing value it will count it. I also tried to use ```.N[!is.na(", rhs, ")]``` instead of just ```.N```, but it did not work.

Comment: Ok, I see .. you may develop you rhs in a paste and add a condition .. but I think it will not be better .. Anyway, there should be something beter to do, but till now I can't see how ..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
my_function <- function(tbl, trt, rhs, blk, stc){
      tbl %>% 
            group_by(vars(matches(blk))) %>% 
            mutate(across(.cols=rhs,.fns=stc,.names=paste0(trt,".{.fn}")))
}


trt <- "New.Name"
rhs <- "TR"
blk <- "GR"
stc <- list(Mean=~mean(.,na.rm=TRUE),Count=~count(.,na.rm=TRUE))

my_function(tbl, trt, rhs, blk, stc)
```